# Pytorch: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Calling `tensor.numpy()` gives the error:

> RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead.

`tensor.cpu().detach().numpy()` gives the same error.

Comment: Calling `var.detach().numpy()`, as stated, is what you want (where `var` is the name of the tensor you want to convert to a `numpy` array). If that's not working for some reason, you'll need to provide more details on what code you're running to get this error. The `torch.exp(...` line isn't relevant. What is `cpu` here? Is that the name of the tensor you want to convert? If so, do `cpu.detach().numpy()`. Or is it a function which returns a tensor?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### Error reproduced

```
import torch

tensor1 = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0],requires_grad=True)

print(tensor1)
print(type(tensor1))

tensor1 = tensor1.numpy()

print(tensor1)
print(type(tensor1))
```

which leads to the exact same error for the line `tensor1 = tensor1.numpy()`:

```
tensor([1., 2.], requires_grad=True)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/badScript.py", line 8, in <module>
    tensor1 = tensor1.numpy()
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### Generic solution

this was suggested to you in your error message, just replace `var` with your variable name

```
import torch

tensor1 = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0],requires_grad=True)

print(tensor1)
print(type(tensor1))

tensor1 = tensor1.detach().numpy()

print(tensor1)
print(type(tensor1))
```

which returns as expected

```
tensor([1., 2.], requires_grad=True)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
[1. 2.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

### Some explanation

You need to convert your tensor to another tensor that isn't requiring a gradient in addition to its actual value definition. This other tensor can be converted to a numpy array. Cf. [this discuss.pytorch post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cant-call-numpy-on-variable-that-requires-grad/20763/2). (I think, more precisely, that one needs to do that in order to get the actual tensor out of its pytorch `Variable` wrapper, cf. [this other discuss.pytorch post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-transform-variable-into-numpy/104/3)).

Comment: This happened to me in second tutorial of fast.ai. In this case, instead of directly using nn.Parameter variables for plotting, copying the detached variables into a separate tensors and plotting them solved the issue.

Comment: For further explanation on why the detach method is needed, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582590/why-do-we-call-detach-before-calling-numpy-on-a-pytorch-tensor) on which I awarded a bounty.

Comment: Use 'tensor1 = tensor1.detach().numpy()' instead of 'tensor1 = tensor1.numpy()'.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same error message but it was for drawing a scatter plot on matplotlib.

There is 2 steps I could get out of this error message :

1. import the `fastai.basics` library with : `from fastai.basics import *`
2. If you only use the `torch` library, remember to take off the `requires_grad` with :

   ```
   with torch.no_grad():
       (your code)
   ```

Comment: What to do after importing fastai.basics ?

Comment: Sorry couldn't answer sooner, once you've imported, you just copy/paste your code in the `with torch.no_grad():` part and just let the magic go

Comment: That is 1 way with 2 steps, not 2 ways.

Comment: I encountered similar problem while doing plot. only doing 2nd step worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this problem
when running through epochs, I recorded the loss to a list

```
final_losses.append(loss)
```

Once I ran through all the epochs I wanted to graph the output

```
plt.plot(range(epochs), final_loss)
plt.ylabel('RMSE Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch');
```

I was running this on my Mac, with no problem, but, I needed to run this on a windows PC and it produced the error noted above. So, I checked the type of each variable.

```
Type(range(epochs)), type(final_losses)
```

> range, list

Seems like it should be OK.

It took a little bit of fidgeting to realize that the final_losses list was a list of tensors. I then converted them to an actual list with a new list variable fi_los.

```
fi_los = [fl.item() for fl in final_losses ]
plt.plot(range(epochs), fi_los)
plt.ylabel('RMSE Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch');
```

Success!

Comment: fi_los = [fl.item() for fl in final_losses], this worked really well in my case

Answer (score 3):

### For existing tensor

```
from torch.autograd import Variable

type(y)  # <class 'torch.Tensor'>

y = Variable(y, requires_grad=True)
y = y.detach().numpy()

type(y)  #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to use `torch.no_grad():` the context manager which disables the tracking of the gradient locally.

Just write your code inside this contact manager like:

```
with torch.no_grad():
   graph_x = some_list_of_numbers
   graph_y = some_list_of_tensors

   plt.plot(graph_x, graph_y)
   plt.show()
```