# loss defined on repeated evaluation of the same model

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have a model denoted by `f()`,

Suppose the target is `t`, `f(x1) = y1` and `f(x2) = y2` and my loss is defined as
`loss = mse(y1,y2) + mse(y2,t)`

Since both `y1` and `y2` reguires grad, I have received error such as

> one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

My understanding is that, suppose I evaluate y1 first, the graph has been changed upon my evaluation of y2. Should I fix some tensor such as ,e.g., `y1_no_grad = y1.detach().numpy()` and then use
`loss = mse(y1_no_grad,y2) + mse(y2,t)`?
However, I still receive error `Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy()`, which I am not sure if it is because y1_no_grad is a numpy array while y2 is a tensor.

**Update:**

I realized my problem afterwards. It was due to that I created multiple loss tensors and that I backwarded one loss tensor first which changed the parameters in-place. This caused error when I wanted to backward another loss tensor.

E.g.

```
f(x1) = y1
f(x2) = y2
f(x3) = y3 
...
f(xn) = yn

f(x) = y

for i in range(n):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = mse(y,yi) + mse(yi,t)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

To me the solutions are either:

1.accumulate the loss tensors before doing backward , i.e.

```
for i in range(n):
    loss = mse(y,yi) + mse(yi,t)
    loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

2.Evaluate again before each backward, i.e.:

```
for i in range(n):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y = f(x)
    yi = f(xi)
    loss = mse(y,yi) + mse(yi,t)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: I suppose this one might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466298/pytorch-cant-call-numpy-on-variable-that-requires-grad-use-var-detach-num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose the target is `t`, `f(x1) = y1` and `f(x2) = y2` and my loss is defined as
> `loss = mse(y1,y2) + mse(y2,t)`
>
> Since both `y1` and `y2` reguires grad, I have received error such as

This statement is incorrect. What you've described does not necessiate in-place assignment errors. For example

```py
import torch
from torch.nn.functional import mse_loss

def f(x):
    return x**2

t = torch.ones(1)

x1 = torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True)
x2 = torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True)

y1 = f(x1)
y2 = f(x2)

loss = mse_loss(y1, y2) + mse_loss(y2, t)
loss.backward()
```

does not produce any errors. Likely your issue is somewhere else.

For the general case you described you should get a computation graph that could be visualized as

[image]

The only issue here could be that your function `f` is not differentiable or is somehow invalid (perhaps in in-place assignment is taking place in `f`).