# When an imported module tries to use numpy, I get an error from pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to graph the loss of my neural network with pyplot. When I try to pass in the arguments to the function like so:

```
dataframe = dict (
    Epoch = epochsArray,
    Loss = lossesArray
)
figure = px.line(dataframe, x='Epoch', y='Loss', title='Loss Per Epoch') #This line is where the error is
```

I get an error from PyTorch: `RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.` How can I call `tensor.detach().numpy()` inside a module that was imported?

Comment: what version of numpy and pytorch you have ?

Comment: numpy version: 1.23.3
pytorch version: 1.13.1
I updated both of them a few days ago

Comment: would using torch.no_grad() work ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56023903/9908000

Comment: I get a different error now 
`RuntimeError: Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment`

Comment: this is why u should store loss using `loss.item()`. You can even use `torch.gather` with `no_grad()`.  However `no_grad()` should work without having to call `deepcopy`.  why is `deepcopy` being called?

Comment: Using loss.item() and no_grad() fixed my issues, thank you